# How to get the events for a Facebook user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the latest version (11.0) of the Facebook API. I'm trying to get user's events using the Graph API Explorer. I can get the user's pages and events for each page, but can't get user's events.

The response of the request with events endpoint is an empty array. After adding `debug=all` to the request, I get the following error `The field 'events' is only accessible on the user object after the user grants the the permission for user events'.` , but there is no permission for user events in Graph API Explorer.

What should I do to get the user's events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, there is no events edge for users anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/#edges

The error message may be misleading.